# How can see the request data?

Tags: python, python-requests

this is my code,i use requests.python2.7

```
 #create requests
    requests_vivo = requests.Session()
    #login url
    login_url = 'https://id.vivo.com.cn/api/login'
    #captcha_url
    captcha_url = 'https://id.vivo.com.cn/api/kaptcha.jpg?t=%.0f' % time.time()
    #header
    header = {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Host": "id.vivo.com.cn",
        "Origin": "https://id.vivo.com.cn",
        "Referer": "https://id.vivo.com.cn/?_%.0f"%time.time(),
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
    }
    #request captcha
    captcha_response = requests_vivo.get(url=captcha_url,headers=header)
    #write jpg
    with open('captcha_pic.jpg','wb') as f:
        f.write(captcha_response.content)

    captcha_code = raw_input('Please input code:')

    #data
    data = {
        "name": setting.username,
        "password": encryptPasswd(setting.password),
        "verificationCode": captcha_code,
        "remember": "0"
    }

    #login request
    login_response = requests_vivo.post(url=login_url,headers=header,data=data)
    print login_response.request.data
```

this is error,i can't see data:

```
#captcha
Please input code:8men
8men

    #error info
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/freedom/work/app/sem/vivo/test.py", line 39, in <module>
        print login_response.request.data
    AttributeError: 'PreparedRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: which version of requests you are using?

Comment: requests==2.18.4@johnII

Answer (score 7):

The Request is turned into a [requests.PreparedRequest](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) when it is sent with `.post()` or `.get()`. Unfortunately that doesn't have the *unencoded* `data` available anymore.

What you can get from a POST response is `login_response.request.body`, but that has been encoded as form data at this point.

To turn it back into a nice to use dict you can use this:

```
# py2
import urlparse
dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(login_response.request.body))
```

or

```
# py3
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
dict(parse_qsl(login_response.request.body))
```

Answer (score 3):

Should you be using below

```
print login_response.text
```

instead of this?

```
 print login_response.request.data
```

basically you are printing the response content not the request that you have sent?

Else request data itself is available for you since you are passing it with the request so if you want you can print it directly e.g.

```
print data
```

Comment: then just print the data itself that you are passing into the request as stated on my answer